# Compile error when using Block<Document> to print collection using Java MongoDB 4.0.4 driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

When using [Java MongoDB Driver 4.0.4](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/), OpenJDK 11 and following the example on [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/read/), seeing a compile error when using `findIterable.forEach(printBlock);`

Also looks like `com.mongodb.Block` http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/tutorials/aggregation/ is not deprecated.

```
public String testLocal() {
  MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("cord");
  MongoCollection<Document> collection1 = database.getCollection("papers");

  FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection1.find(new Document());
  findIterable.forEach(printBlock);

}

public Block<Document> printBlock = new Block<Document>() {
  @Override
  public void apply(final Document document) {
    System.out.println(document.toJson());
  }
};
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] /Projects/cord/src/main/java/com/engg/java/cord/services/PrimaryService_Local.java:
[24,30] incompatible types: com.mongodb.Block<org.bson.Document> cannot be converted
 to java.util.function.Consumer<? super org.bson.Document>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to write the line `findIterable.forEach(printBlock);` to `findIterable.forEach(doc -> printBlock.apply(doc));` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation obviously is outdated. If you look at the javadocs for FindIterable
(http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html) you'll see that `forEach` is inherited from `java.lang.Iterable` which takes a `Consumer` as a parameter, not a `Block`.

Thus, replace your printBlock declaration with:

```
public Consumer<Document> printBlock = document -> System.out.println(document.toJson());
```

... and all shall be fine.

Answer (score 0):

With help from [mtj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5506086/mtj) and Mongodb support, adding working code blocks..

```
public String testLocal() {
  MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("cord");
  MongoCollection<Document> collection1 = database.getCollection("papers");

  FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection1.find(new Document());
  findIterable.forEach((Consumer<Document>)  d -> System.out.println( d.toJson())); 
}
```

or

```
public Consumer<Document> printBlock = document -> System.out.println(document.toJson());

public String testLocal() {
  MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("cord");
  MongoCollection<Document> collection1 = database.getCollection("papers");

  FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection1.find(new Document());
  findIterable.forEach(printBlock);
}
```

or with reference to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-13638

```
public String testLocal() {
  MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("cord");
  MongoCollection<Document> collection1 = database.getCollection("papers");

  FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection1.find(new Document());
  findIterable.forEach(printBlock);
}

Consumer<Document> printBlock = new Consumer<Document>() {
  public void accept(final Document doc) {
    System.out.println(doc.toJson());
  };
};
```